# MsBuild task and scope of properties

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have one build project with target build

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="Version : $(FullVersionNr)"  />
    <MSBuild Projects="@(WebProj)"  Properties="WebProjectOutputDir=$(SitePublishPath);OutDir=$(SitePublishPath1);Configuration=$(Configuration)" />      
<Message Text="Version  : $(FullVersionNr)"  />
```

and during build I set $(FullVersionNr) to accurate assembly number and it's not this nr at the end

I even declared $(FullVersionNr) prop in another file

```
<Import Project="Common.proj"/>
```

and it's not getting out.

It's only one way communication from parent to child project, and I want it to be bi-directional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This MSDN article should give you a few ideas on how to achieve this: [MSBuild Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx). More specifically, this blog post should answer your scope questions: [Scope of properties and item in an MSBuild script](http://blog.qetza.net/en/tag/msbuild/). Be sure to read the summary at the end.

So if you are batching over multiple projects, it is possible that the local contexts have not been merged back into the global context when you access the `$(FullVersionNr)` for the second time, or that one local context has overwritten another (i.e. two child projects, the first updates the build, but the second doesn't).

One possible solution for you is to use registry properties as described in the MSDN article, and only write the property when its value is updated.

Comment: About second link and conclusions - "When a target execution ends, the updated values in the local context are merged back to the global context." - in my case It's **NOT** merged back to global context

Comment: @Krzy, do you have more than one project in the `@(WebProj)` list? If so, set `$(FullVersionNr)` to something unique and predictable in each one, rerun your build, and see what the value is at the end. If it is still the same as the original value then none of the contexts have been merged. If it is different then you can track which project changed it.

Comment: It's one web project and rest of the projects are build as depended projects. All of them set the same version number and at the end this value is not returned to first project in which line 
    <MSBuild Projects="@(WebProj)"  > 
is